# How to solve java reverse integer leetcode problem

Tags: java

Tried all the ways to pass the test case but it still shows only one error. I do not know how to rectify the error.

**Input:** 1534236469
**Actual Output:** 1056389759
**Expected Output:** 0

I do not know why my code does not give output 0.

```java
class Solution
{
    public static int reverse(int x)
    {
        boolean flag = false;
        if (x < 0)
        {
            x = 0 - x;
            flag = true;
        }
        int res = 0;
        int p = x;
        while (p > 0)
        {
            int mod = p % 10;
            p = p / 10;
            res = res * 10 + mod;
        }
        if (res > Integer.MAX_VALUE)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        if (flag)
        {
            res = 0 - res;
        }
        return res;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = sc.nextInt();
        int revinteger = reverse(x);
        System.out.println(revinteger);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, describe the problem that your code wants to solve (don't assume we know every leetcode problem), and please, format/indent your code so it gets readable.

Answer (score 2):

The statement `res > Integer.MAX_VALUE` will never be true as `res` is of `int` datatype. And an *int* can never be larger than the *Integer.MAX_VALUE* (MAX_VALUE is itself the max we can store as int).
Use `long` datatype for reversing the number instead and at the end return the integer value of the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (res > Integer.MAX_VALUE)
```

If it's the max possible value of the integer, how will it ever be greater than it? You'll have to detect it in another way.

One way would be to use the `long` data type instead of `int`. Then, it can become larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, and that catch will work.

Otherwise, you can probably find another way to catch that case.

Answer (score 0):

Because long based operations are relatively slow, I would only use a `long` to do the final check to determine if overflow is about to occur.

It should be obvious that no `int` will cause overflow if all the digits except the last are reversed. So process the last digit outside of the loop before returning the value.  The border case for min is eliminated first to facilitate subsequent processing.  Now only `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is of concern for both positive and negative numbers.

```
public static int reverse(int v) {
    if (v == Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
        return 0; // guaranteed overflow if reversed.
    }
    int rev = 0; 
    long ovflLimit = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int sign = v < 0 ? -1 : 1;
    v *=sign;
    
    while (v > 9) {
        int digit = v % 10;
        rev =  rev * 10 + digit;
        v/=10;
    }
    long ovfl = (long)(rev)*10+v;
    return ovfl > ovflLimit ? 0 : (int)(ovfl)*sign;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved in various ways but if we stick to `Java` and your solution then as it already have been pointed out in some of the answers that by using `int` the condition `if(res > Integer.MAX_VALUE)` will never be `true`.
Hence you would not get expected output as 0.

You can put a check before reversing last digit by casting the value in `long` and check if it's out of `int` limit. As suggested by WJS.

In case you want to stick to your solution without much change below is the working code for the same.

```
class Solution {

    public static int reverse(int x) {
        boolean flag = false;
        long input = x;
        if (input < 0) {
            input = 0 - input;
            flag = true;
        }

        long res = 0;
        long p = input;

        while (p > 0) {
            long mod = p % 10;
            p = p / 10;
            res = res * 10 + mod;
        }

        if (res > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            return 0;
        }

        if (flag) {
            res = 0 - res;
        }

        return (int) res;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = sc.nextInt();
        int revInteger = reverse(x);
        System.out.println(revInteger);
    }
}
```